# Synchronizing alternately two processes in Linux C

Tags: c, linux

I need two child processes to do this:

- Child process 1 should `printf` even numbers between 0 and 100.
- Child process 2 should `printf` odd  numbers between 0 and 100.

What I should see in terminal after execution is: `0 1 2 4..100`

How can I do this?

I tried this program, but it doesn't work, it only gives me the first integer 0:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler1(int sig)
{
  if(sig == SIGCONT)
  {
     raise(SIGCONT);
  }
}

void handler2(int sig)
{
  if(sig == SIGCONT)
  {
     raise(SIGCONT);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int i=-1;

  if(fork()==0)
  { 
     signal(SIGCONT,handler1);
     while(1)
     {

        printf("%d\n",i+1);
        pause();
        kill(getpid()+1,SIGCONT);
     }
  }

  if(fork()==0)
  {
     signal(SIGCONT,handler2);
     while(1)
     {
       pause();

       printf("%d\n",i+1);
       kill(getpid()-1,SIGCONT);
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: zillions of problems.. print some debug messages and (hopefully...) you'll see what's going on

Answer (score 2):

Signals are not a good solution for this problem. The first signal gets lost (it is sent by the first child before the second child starts), and you end up locked (because one of the processes is waiting for a signal that it had already missed).

Try using semaphores or message queues instead. They are immune to this problem, because they don't get lost in the system, even when not all processes involved are already started.

Comment: I see. However I'm a bit confused, because this was given as a homework asking us to do synchronization using exit/wait or using signals, wich are the things we learnt about until now. I don't know how to use semaphores or message queues yet. Is there any possibility tu use these? 

Thanks for your answer.